# What´s the measure of the radius of the cirle below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> In the figure, $ABCD$ is a rectangle, $M$ and $N$ are points of tangency . Knowing that $MB= \sqrt2, OC =3 , ND=2$ calculate the radius of the circle. (Answer: $\sqrt3$)
>
> [image]

My progress:

Let $MB = a,~  OC = b$ and $ND = c$

$A$ is the point of tangency?

Therefore $O,~A,~B$ are collinear

Using Pythagoras in $\triangle OBM$ and $\triangle BCO$

$OB^2=r^2+a^2\tag I$
$b^2=c^2+OB^2\tag{II}$

From $(I)$ and $(II)$: $r^2=b^2-a^2-c^2$

Therefore $r=\sqrt{9-4-2}=\sqrt3$

In this solution, point $A$ was considered as the point of tangency. But this was not mentioned in the statement. Is it possible to demonstrate this or is there another kind of solution?

Comment: You can't assume A is point of tangency!!

Comment: @Tojra  ??? But this was precisely the doubt ..if there was an error in the statement or if there is another way to solve it without considering the tangency

Comment: A sketch with GeoGebra suggests that tangency is not necessary, but that in any case a solution is possible only if $r=\sqrt3$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca  Curious..there is another similar question, one only the data is literal and the answer gives $r=\sqrt{b^2-a^2-c^2}$

Comment: @MathLover  Could you give an opinion?

Comment: @petaarantes,  I can not see your drawing because of problem with internet. Can you please describe the statement in more details(how figure must be).

Comment: @sirous  Hi...See if you can through the link..  https://i.servimg.com/u/f89/19/66/19/59/fig2a11.jpg

Comment: @petaarantes, Sorry but we do not have real internet in this country. I could not use the link either.

Comment: @sirous  I'll try to explain... we have a circle and a rectangle supported on this circle with its upper left vertex (A) .. then we have the upper tangent that passes through the upper right vertex (B) of the rectangle and the point of tangency M on the circle and lower tangent that touches the circle at N and passes through the lower left vertex D of the rectangle. The circle has center O and radius r.

Comment: even if you try and tag me, unfortunately your message does not reach me unless I have been to the question and commented or answered. Life is a bit busy right now.

Comment: It is a well known identity in $2D$ that sum of square of distances from an external or internal point to the vertices on each diagonal of a rectangle are equal. Here $O$ is the external point so $OA^2 + OC^2 = OB^2 + OD^2$

Comment: @MathLover  grateful for the return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is indeed quite simple. We just need a preliminary result (easy to prove): if $S$ is the midpoint of a segment $PQ$ and $H$ is the projection of point $R$ on line $PQ$, then the signed distance of $H$ from $S$ is:
$$
HS={PR^2-QR^2\over 2PQ}.
$$

Let then $H$, $K$ be the projections of $O$ on lines $AD$, $BC$. Their signed distances from the midpoints of $AD$ and $BC$ must be the same, thus from the above lemma we get:
$$
{OA^2-OD^2\over2AD}={OB^2-OC^2\over2BC}.
$$
But $AD=BC$, hence it must be $OA^2-OD^2=OB^2-OC^2$, that is:
$$
(r^2+2)-9=r^2-(r^2+4),
\quad\text{i.e.}\quad r^2=3.
$$

Comment: Do you have a link to this theorem?

Comment: @petaarantes https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1033597/255730

Comment: Thank for all!!

Comment: A formula wouldn't it be? $\frac{OA^2−OD^2}{2AD}=\frac{OB^2−OC^2}{2BC} \iff OA^2-OD^2 = OB^2 - OC^2$

Comment: @petaarantes That's what I wrote. A previous version had $4$ instead of $2$, but I corrected the typo.